# org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.exception.RemoteTransportException: Lost connection to task manager

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-flink

I'm working on a **project that uses flink** (**Version - 1.4.2**) for bulk data ingestion to **my graph database** (**Janusgraph**). Data ingestion has two phases, one is vertex data ingestion and the other is edge data ingestion to graph db. **Vertex data ingestion runs without any issue but during edge ingestion** i'm getting an error saying **Lost connection to task manager taskmanagerName**. The detailed error traceback from `flink-taskmanager-b6f46f6c8-fgtlw` is attached below:

```
2019-08-01 18:13:26,025 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask 
  - Error in task code:  CHAIN Join(Remap EDGES id: TO) -> Map (Key Extractor) -> Combine (Deduplicate edges including bi-directional edges) (62/80)
org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.exception.RemoteTransportException: Lost connection to task manager 'flink-taskmanager-b6f46f6c8-gcxnm/10.xx.xx.xx:6121'. 
This indicates that the remote task manager was lost.
at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.PartitionRequestClientHandler.exceptionCaught(PartitionRequestClientHandler.java:146)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:275)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:253)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.exceptionCaught(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:131)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:275)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:253)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.exceptionCaught(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:131)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:275)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:253)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerAdapter.exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerAdapter.java:79)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:275)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:253)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireExceptionCaught(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:835)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.handleReadException(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:87)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:162)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:311)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:881)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:241)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
... 6 more
```

For ease of understanding lets say:

`flink-taskmanager-b6f46f6c8-gcxnm` as TM1 and

`flink-taskmanager-b6f46f6c8-fgtlw` as TM2

On debugging I was able to find that the **TM1 requested for `ResultPartition (RPP)` from  TM2 and the TM2 started to send ResultPartition to TM1**. But on checking the logs from **TM1** we found that it **waited for long time to get RP from TM2** but **after some time it started to deregister the accepted task**. We believe deregistring task after netty remote transport exception caused TM2 to send `Lost Taskmanager` error for the specific job.
Both **taskmanagers are running in separate ec2 instance (m4.2xlarge)**. I have verified **cpu and memory utilization of both instances** and was able to see **all metric within limit**.

Can you please tell me why taskmanager is acting weird like this and a way to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

### **Flushing Buffers to Netty**

In the picture above, the credit-based flow control mechanics actually sit inside the “Netty Server” (and “Netty Client”) components and the buffer the RecordWriter is writing to is always added to the result subpartition in an empty state and then gradually filled with (serialised) records. But when does Netty actually get the buffer? Obviously, it cannot take bytes whenever they become available since that would not only add substantial costs due to cross-thread communication and synchronisation, but also make the whole buffering obsolete.

In Flink, there are three situations that make a buffer available for consumption by the Netty server:

a buffer becomes full when writing a record to it, or
the buffer timeout hits, or
a special event such as a checkpoint barrier is sent.

### **Flush after Buffer Full**

The RecordWriter works with a local serialisation buffer for the current record and will gradually write these bytes to one or more network buffers sitting at the appropriate result subpartition queue. Although a RecordWriter can work on multiple subpartitions, each subpartition has only one RecordWriter writing data to it. The Netty server, on the other hand, is reading from multiple result subpartitions and multiplexing the appropriate ones into a single channel as described above. This is a classical producer-consumer pattern with the network buffers in the middle and as shown by the next picture. After (1) serialising and (2) writing data to the buffer, the RecordWriter updates the buffer’s writer index accordingly. Once the buffer is completely filled, the record writer will (3) acquire a new buffer from its local buffer pool for any remaining bytes of the current record - or for the next one - and add the new one to the subpartition queue. This will (4) notify the Netty server of data being available if it is not aware yet4. Whenever Netty has capacity to handle this notification, it will (5) take the buffer and send it along the appropriate TCP channel.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pruWU.png)

We can assume it already got the notification if there are more finished buffers in the queue.

### **Flush after Buffer Timeout**

In order to support low-latency use cases, we cannot only rely on buffers being full in order to send data downstream. There may be cases where a certain communication channel does not have too many records flowing through and unnecessarily increase the latency of the few records you actually have. Therefore, a periodic process will flush whatever data is available down the stack: the output flusher. The periodic interval can be configured via StreamExecutionEnvironment#setBufferTimeout and acts as an upper bound on the latency5 (for low-throughput channels). The following picture shows how it interacts with the other components: the RecordWriter serialises and writes into network buffers as before but concurrently, the output flusher may (3,4) notify the Netty server of data being available if Netty is not already aware (similar to the “buffer full” scenario above). When Netty handles this notification (5) it will consume the available data from the buffer and update the buffer’s reader index. The buffer stays in the queue - any further operation on this buffer from the Netty server side will continue reading from the reader index next time.

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nJwr.png)

**Reference:**

Below link may help you out.

[flink-network-stack-details](https://flink.apache.org/2019/06/05/flink-network-stack.html)

Answer (score 1):

Can you check the GC logs of **TM1** and **TM2** to see if there were full GCs which may cause heatbeat timeout.